# Is it common to use (for example) "Obviously $a \leq b$..." is equivalent to "Let $a \leq b$..."?

Tags: notation

I am reading several works of an author. I have identified in one of the works, what he meant by "Obviously $a \leq b$..." is the same as "Let $a \leq b$...", since (I think) it is absurd if the construction given implies $a \leq b$.

In another work of his, I have not managed to eliminate the possibility where due to the construction $c \leq d$, yet the sentence "Obviously $c \leq d$..." is present.

Thus I would like to know if this style of writing is common, or am I possibly missing something from the construction. The works of the author concerned is a famous (in the field) book, and a paper of his. This is the second paper I'm reading, that is why I'm still not used to the lingo.

I put the tag notation as I don't know what else suits this.

**Edit:**

The paper I am unsure about can be found [here](http://ftp.cs.elte.hu/%7Elovasz/scans/perfect.pdf), proof of Thm 5, "Obviously, $x_0^T \leq w_0$."

The book where I thought the two phrases might be equivalent is Matching Theory, by Laszlo Lovasz and Michael Plummer. Can be found on page 470, proof of theorem 12.3.3, "Obviously $v \not\in T_1 \cup T_2$". I don't think $H'-E_i$ must not use $v$ as a vertex cover, that is why I thought "Obviously..." here means "Let...".

Comment: Can you link the paper? It is hard to judge without context.

Comment: Please quote examples where you've seen _obviously_ (or e.g. _clearly_) & _let_ so we can understand why you think they're synonyms. They're not. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality).

Comment: Those phrases are certanly not equivalent.  For the first, we must have defined both $a$ and $b$ and then we remark that the latter is not less than the former.  For the second, we need not have defined either of them (perhaps we are just choosing two any two values which satisfy the desired inequality) or we have just defined one of the values and are choosing the other subject to that inequality.

Comment: @Andreas The paper can be found here http://ftp.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/perfect.pdf, proof of Thm 5, "Obviously, $x_0^T \leq w_0$."

Comment: @J.G. I will add it in the question

Comment: In that paper, what (partial?) order is the author using for vectors?  What does it mean to write that $\vec v≤ \vec u$?  Lexicographic?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu the $a \leq b$ is just an example, but I edited the question and added the paper and the book.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes In that example, "obviously" does not mean "let". The proof says: Let $w_0$ be any $(0,1)$-vector and use it as $w$ in equation (11). Then let $x_0$ be a solution of equation (11) with the greatest possible number of zeros. The statement "obviously, $x_0^T \leq w_0$" then follows from these definitions.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes More generally, I have never seen "let" and "obviously" used synonymously. The former is a definition and the latter is a (supposedly) easy deduction.

Comment: @Andreas yes I just realized we can force each co-ordinate of $x_0$ to be 0 if the same co-ordinate for $w_0$= 0. The solution would still be feasible, and doesn't affect objective value. Thus the co-ordinates of $x_0$ are 1 only when the same co-ordinate for $w_0$ is not 0, and from here comes $x_0^T \leq w_0$. I should have realized this earlier, and not ask a silly question

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes Don't beat yourself up; asking questions is how you can learn.